# trying to convert excel to json file

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have an excel file and I want to convert it json file. To do this I wrote this vba codes

```
Dim excelRange As Range
Dim jsonItems As New Collection
Dim jsonDictionary As New Dictionary
Dim jsonFileObject As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim jsonFileExport As TextStream
Dim a As Long
Dim cell As Variant

Set excelRange = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion


For a = 2 To excelRange.Rows.Count
    jsonDictionary("referance") = Cells(i, 1)
    jsonDictionary("engType") = "A5"
    jsonDictionary("refType") = Cells(i, 6)

    jsonItems.Add jsonDictionary
    Set jsonDictionary = Nothing
Next a


Dim o As String
o = InputBox("Enter Name you want to use")
Set jsonFileExport = jsonFileObject.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\ftk1187\Desktop\" & o & ".json", True)
jsonFileExport.WriteLine (JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, whiteSpace:=3))
```

When I run my codes, the program gives me **object required** error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @braX It's stopping last line.

Comment: Try adding an `Option Explicit` statement in the top of the module and put the tick to "Tools -> Options -> Require Variable Declaration" setting . I've copied your code and it tells me that `JsonConverter` and `i` variables is not defined.

Comment: It seems this code tries to use a component `JsonConverter`, maybe [this one](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)? Did you download and install it? Besides that, your loop variable in the `For` lines is named `a`, but you used `i`in the loop body. **Always use Option Explicit** to avoid such errors.